# Changing element's background image with jQuery won't take

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm using a combination of the following examples of code to change the `background-image` css value, depending on whether a separate element contains a string of text.

The separate element appears on the page multiple times (wordpress post meta data), so this jQuery should run everytime the criteria is met.

```
$(window).load(function(){
if ($(".postmetadata").contains("Seattle")) {
        $(this).closest(".boxy").find(".storyNoIMG")
        .addClass('.seattleIMG');
    } else {
    }
});
```

Here is the second example I'm using:

```
            var imageURL = "images/seattle.png";

            if ($(".postmetadata").contains("Seattle")) {
                $(this).closest(".boxy").find(".storyNoIMG")
                .css("background-image","url(" + "images/seattle.png" + ")");
            }
```

Here is the html context:

```
        <div class="boxy">
            <div class="boxGrad">

                <div class="postmetadata">
                    <?php echo time_ago(); ?> •
                    <?php the_category(' • ') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="articleTitle">
                    <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="exPand">
                </div>
            <div class="rightCtrls">

                <!-- heart + -->
                <?php echo getPostLikeLink(get_the_ID());?>
                    <div  class="imageGlass">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/media/imageMag-02.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end post right controls -->                 
                <div class="ajaxBoxLoadSource">
                    <iframe class="ajaxIframe"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="storyNoImg"></div>
            <div class="articleImageThumb">
                <a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true)) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true); else the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'original'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end boxy -->
```

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `contains` method, it supports `:contains` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you're trying to do:

```
$(".postmetadata:contains('Seattle')").each(function(){
    $(this).closest(".boxy").find(".storyNoImg").css("background-image","url(" + "images/seattle.png" + ")");
});
```

First you filter the elements you need, then you loop through them with `each()`

Also as it has been noted, there's no `contains()` method for jQuery objects and you don't use the dot when adding a class

Comment: `<div class="storyNoImg"></div>` and `.find(".storyNoIMG")` doesn't match

Comment: Selectors! This works flawlessly. Now to get the `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` into a `var`...